# Python/Pandas - Given a specific date, find the previous date in the list

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a list of dates. And given a specific input date, want to find the previous date in the list. Example is:

```
my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30'].
InputDate = '2019-07-15'
```

the output should be '2019-06-30' because it is the previous date of the `InputDate` found in the list. Note that the `InputDate` is not necessarily found in the `my_dates_list`.

Another example: if `InputDate` is '2019-03-01', the output should be `2019-02-28`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to subtract the `InputDate` to each date in the list, find the minimum element (*greater than 0*) in the list and use it to index `my_dates_list`:

```
import datetime as datetime

in_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(InputDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
l = [in_date - datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in my_dates_list]
# [datetime.timedelta(165), datetime.timedelta(137), datetime.timedelta(106)...
my_dates_list[l.index(min(i for i in l if i>datetime.timedelta(0)))]
# '2019-06-30'
```

Comment: I would put absolute value over min (or while you are creating l for all its elements)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out @GrzegorzSkibinski !! there was an obvious error here, I want the `min` of the values that are > 0

Answer (score 1):

A solution using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30']
test_date = '2019-03-01'

# change to datetime
my_dates_list = pd.to_datetime(my_dates_list)
test_date = pd.to_datetime(test_date)

# get less than test date, sort and take first value
my_dates_list[my_dates_list < test_date].sort_values(ascending=False)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the strings into datetime objects (for example `pd.datetime`) and then just find the maximum value that is smaller than the date you are looking for:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30']
InputDate = '2019-07-15'

my_dates_list = pd.to_datetime(my_dates_list)
InputDate = pd.to_datetime(InputDate)

print(max(my_dates_list[my_dates_list<InputDate]))
```

This returns

```
2019-06-30 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to combine the search of year/month/day and put an if-condition in a while-loop to check if the date is in the list; otherwise, it has to decrease the day maintaining the same month/year. If the search gives out no results, then it has to decrease the month, and eventually the year. It is a brute force solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `min` with a custom key

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30']
InputDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-07-15', '%Y-%m-%d')

print(min(my_dates_list, key=lambda x: InputDate - datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')))
# --> 2019-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list of dates which is no bigger than InputDate, then take the 'largest' value.

```
max([x for x in my_dates_list if InputDate >= x])
```

or

```
max(my_dates_list, key= lambda x:x if x<=InputDate else '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Аnother simple solution. It's not only suitable for dates.

```
def previous_date(dt: datetime, dates_list: list):
    """ get previous date"""

    dates_list.append(dt)
    sorted_list = sorted(set(dates_list))
    dt_index = sorted_list.index(dt)

    return sorted_list[dt_index-1] if dt_index != 0 else dt
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using bisect(Python Standard Library):

```
from bisect import bisect

def get_previous_date(dt: datetime, dates_list: list):
    dt_index = bisect(dates_list, dt)
    return sorted_list[dt_index-1] if dt_index != 0 else dt
```